# IIS Site Bindings

Tags: binding, iis-6

I have a web website in IIS 6.1, with a Self-signed SSL. The website contains 3 web applications, all setup to use https as binding. Whenever I browse the application, the URL shows as

```
https://localhost/mysite1/default.aspx
```

I was under the impression that by adding a Site binding to use the computer name instead would change the URL to something like:

```
https://myservername/mysite1/default.aspx,
```

which means it will no longer complain about the SSL certificate being invalid when accessing the website, as the SSL is issued by "myservername"

I used the following command:

cscript.exe //nologo %systemdrive%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/2/SecureBindings “:443:myservername”

My application identifier (2), which is shown under the "Sites" node.

After running the command, the URL is now directing to:

https://myservername.xn--9o0a/mysite1/default.aspx

That obviously doesn't work... it added .xn--9o0a to the URL??? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some googling I managed to find this article that explains everything and how to fix the issue I was having.

http://gavinmckay.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/howto-fix-wcf-host-name-on-iis/